# In VB.NET check for changes in a file launched with process.start()

Tags: c#, vb.net, process, kill-process

I'm developing a vbnet/c#.NET based application that opens files with different applications(excel, word, etc).

The application is launched using `Dim app As Process = Process.Start(ProcessProperties)`

Now, when I have to terminate the process I use `app.Kill()` but I need to check if the document has been modified before killing it.

How can I handle that? And if it's possible, how can I launch the application native prompt for save?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For office applications use [Office Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), not `Process.Start` to start and control them. Here is an example code for Excel (in VB.NET). You should add `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` to the project references in order for this to work.

```vb
   oExcel = New Microsof.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
   oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
   'Do your stuff
   oBook.Close 'This will trigger the application native prompt if the document was modified
   oExcel.Quit()
```

For other programs it depends much on a program

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve behaviour close to what you require by calling [`Process.CloseMainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow) rather than `Process.Kill`.

> The behavior of `CloseMainWindow` is identical to that of a user closing an application's main window using the system menu. Therefore, the request to exit the process by closing the main window does not force the application to quit immediately.
>
> Data edited by the process or resources allocated to the process can be lost if you call `Kill`. `Kill` causes an abnormal process termination, and should be used only when necessary. `CloseMainWindow` enables an orderly termination of the process and closes all windows, so it is preferable for applications with an interface.

In the case of Office applications with unsaved changes, `CloseMainWindow` would launch the Save dialog. You would need to handle scenarios where the users presses “Cancel”, since that may result in the `WaitForExit` call blocking indefinitely.

For example:

```
// Launch Word application.
Process wordProcess = 
    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\winword.exe");

// Give user some time to type in text.
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

// Request Word to close.
wordProcess.CloseMainWindow();

// Wait until user saves or discards changes.
// May block indefinitely if user cancels.
wordProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for this problem. You can calculate some sort of initial check-sum and see whether your document has any changes by redoing the check-sum and comparing against the original one.

This part is not very clear from your question, If the document gets saved, probably you can look at the date_modified value of the file to see whether there has been any modifications.

Comment: I think the OP means unsaved changes.  Although that's not entirely clear.